# Aligning UIButton to the right of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, autolayout

I am using Xcode's interface builder to construct a simple `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` design, where the `UILabel` should be aligned to the left and the `UIButton` (the install button in the screenshot below) aligned to the right.

No matter what combination of constraints I use, I cannot seem to fix this layout issue. Every time I build and run, the install button is always forced towards the left of the screen. Please take a look at the two screenshots below to understand the issue better. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: yourbutton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

Comment: Please change UITextAlignmentRight to NSTextAlignmentRight

Comment: not label but UIButton text title working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
yourbutton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: you have code in tableviewcellforrowatindexpath method?

Comment: Give me Github link i check it and told u